# Find the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum of $f(x) = xe^{−x^2/50}$

Tags: calculus

in the interval $[−2, 10]$. I found the absolute maximum to be  $5e^{-1/2}$ but I can't find the absolute minimum to save my life.

Comment: Consider **endpoints**. (There is only one real candidate.)

Comment: Would it be -2?

Comment: work out $f(-2)$ and $f(10)$ see which is smaller.

Comment: Yes, the min occurs at $-2$. The other endpoint $10$ in principle is a candidate, but there the function is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $f(x) = xe^{(-x^2/50)}$ gives $$f'(x) = e^{(-x^2/50)} + x(-x/25)e^{(-x^2/50)} = 0 \iff 1 - x^2/25 = 0 \iff x = 5 \lor x=- 5$$ Note $-5$ is not in the domain, so you can only take $x = 5$.

Now, $$f(-2) = (-2)e^{(-4/50)} = -1.8462 \text{,} \;\; f(5) = 5e^{(-1/2)} = 3.0326 \;\; \text{and} \;\; f(10) = 10e^{(-2)} = 1.3533$$ so minimum value of $f$ is $f(-2) = -1.8462$

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.